# WebDriver + Internet Explorer, switchTo.window issue

Tags: java, internet-explorer, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I use Selenium 2 + Java for testing the application on IE 9. 
After clicking on the link, the pop-up window is opened. I use switchTo.window method for going to pop-up window. But when I try to go back, my test is delayed on this operation and doesn't go on.

Some code:

```
link.click(); //Open pop-up window    
Object[] windows = driverIE.getWindowHandles().toArray();    
driverIE.switchTo().defaultContent();    
driverIE.switchTo().window(windows[1].toString());  //Focus on pop-up window    
.....    
mainWindowHandle = driverIE.getWindowHandles().iterator().next();   //Handle of main window    
driverIE.switchTo().window(mainWindowHandle);   //Fail!
```

Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Try "mainWindowHandle = driverIE.currentWindowHandle;" before you switch to the popup window.

Comment: Operations "mainWindowHandle = driverIE.getWindowHandles().iterator().next();" and "mainWindowHandle = driverIE.getWindowHandle; before I switch to the popup window" return the same value. The trouble appears in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Windows handles returned by `getWindowHandles()` are not guaranteed to be in any order. In other words, you cannot depend on `windows[1]` in your code sample above to contain the window handle of the opened window. Rather, you need code that looks something like the following (**NOTE:** Completely untested code ahead!):

```
String mainHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();

// Do whatever you need to do to open a new window,
// and properly wait for the new window to appear...

Set<String> allHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
for(String currentHandle : allHandles) {
  // Note that this is cheating a bit. It will only
  // work with a total of two windows. If you have
  // more than two windows total, your logic here
  // will have to be a little more sophisticated.
  if (!currentHandle.equals(mainHandle)) {
    driver.switchTo().window(currentHandle);
    break;
  }
}

// Work with popup window...
// Close the popup window and switch context back
// to the main window.
driver.close();
driver.switchTo().window(mainHandle);
```

Comment: I understand this moment. But the problem appears if I CORRECTLY identify the main window and try to switch to it. Exception is not appear!

Comment: How are you defining "popup window"? Is it a JavaScript dialog spawned by the `alert()`, `confirm()` or `prompt()` functions? Is it a regular browser window that can be resized and allows you to manually set focus back to the original window? Is it a browser window opened by the JavaScript `showModalDialog()` function?

Comment: It is a regular browser window that can be resized and allows you to manually set focus back to the original window.

Comment: I would need to see more of your code, including the site it's coded against (or one that acts as the site it's coded against) to offer more information. There are a number of integration tests in the WebDriver project that do exactly this sort of scenario, without any sort of hang, so it's not globally broken for every site. If you can provide a complete example here, I might be able to give you further guidance.

Comment: Sorry, but I can not give you access to the site. But I can also say that there are a lot of Iframes on this site. I click on the link that are on the Iframe of the second level. After that, a pop-up window apears.

Comment: Hence the request to have a link to a site that "acts [like] the site" your code is running against. It doesn't have to be **your** site, just a site that reproduces the problem. Failing that, there's nothing else that anyone can do to help you.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the issue. Unfortunately, it is not reproduced on other sites.

Comment: The problem doesn't reproduce against just any site, as you've proven for yourself. Ergo, it must be something unique to the site you're testing. Surely you can see that without some sample HTML that reproduces the problem (**not**, I reiterate, necessarily the site you're running against), there's no way anyone can magically tell you where the problem is. There may well be a problem in WebDriver, or it may be a problem in your code, but without sample HTML and a complete example of your code, there's just no way to tell.

Answer (score 0):

As JimEvans stated, driver.getWindowHandles() sometimes puts windows in incorrect order, thus the for loop does not always work.

Similar to above worked for me (I only have two windows to handle):

```
    String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();

    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a")).click();

    Set<String> winHandle = driver.getWindowHandles();

    winHandle.remove(winHandleBefore);

    String winHandleNew = winHandle.toString();

    String winHandleFinal = winHandleNew.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]","");

    driver.switchTo().window(winHandleFinal);
```